# Can the Universal selector * be replaced by :lang?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The universal selector asterisk (*) is unique in that it matches a single element of any type.

So if I have different elements within a div and I want to select them all with one selector, I can either add a class to all the inner elements (something like `.parent .class {}`) or I can use the universal selector (`.parent * {}`)

Then I saw [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#lang) for the :lang pseudo element (particularly the end):

> Note the difference between [lang|=xx] and :lang(xx). In this HTML
>   example, only the BODY matches [lang|=fr] (because it has a LANG
>   attribute) **but both the BODY and the P match :lang(fr) (because both
>   are in French**).

```
<body lang=fr>
  <p>Je suis Français.</p>
</body>
```

Which means that all elements within an element targeted by `:lang` selector are also targeted. (Wow!)

So let's say I wanted to add a border to all the elements within a div - instead of the selector `div * {}` I could theoretically use `:lang`

### [Here's a demo](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/QNWBav)

As far as I can tell, the only difference is that the `:lang` selector selects the parent as well as all the children (and of course there's the technical difference the :lang has greater specificity)....**however**

if the :lang selector was applied in a semantic way that it included the whole document - with the lang **attribute** on the html element - I don't think that the above difference would matter.

So basically my question is:

Assuming that my html element has the attribute `lang="en"`:

Can I replace code which uses the universal selector such like:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

with:

```
:lang(en) {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The code seems to work ([DEMO](http://codepen.io/pen/?editors=1100)), and it seems to be semantic as well, but I'm wondering if there are certain reasons/cons to the above technique.

Comment: What if you add `lang="ch"` in your last div for example?

Comment: Usually a document is written in one language, but even if I add sections in a different language - there's a good chance that I would like to style that section separately anyway

Comment: I'm curious why you would want to use `lang` instead. To me, the intent is totally different. One is "all elements" and the other is "elements of this language" which just happen to be the same thing in your case, but conceptually are different. If your intent is "all elements" then I prefer `*` because it is less characters and more universally recognized. IMO `lang` should be reserved for pages that actually have different languages displayed that need to style them differently.

Comment: Yes, in general you are right, though one could have a text in multiple languages, with only one language visible at a time. Anyway my example was meant to show that the `:lang` and `*` are not interchangeable: all English elements maybe different from all elements.

Comment: @CodingWithSpike maybe there could be some kind of performance gain? although I admit that I have heard that using the universal selector in such a way doesn't effect performance

Comment: @CodingWithSpike - Actually I think it's the fact that the `:lang` selector works that way in the first place - that it selects each and every child - which is super counter-intuitive - that's what got me thinking: 'what should we do with this?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the Universal selector * be replaced by :lang?

No, because you cannot write a selector using `:lang()` that is guaranteed to match all elements unless you assume all elements in the document will always be in the same language.<sup>1</sup>

If you're going to assume that all elements are in the same language, then using the `:lang()` pseudo is pretty pointless, since the whole point of that pseudo-class is to be able to distinguish parts of the document that differ in their content language.

Also note that the compound selector `:lang(en)` (consisting of just that one simple selector) is equivalent to `*:lang(en)`. It is essentially the `*` selector with an additional qualification of a pseudo-class. You are not avoiding the use `*` by replacing it with `:lang()`.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-lang-pseudo) allows a selector like `:lang('*')` to be written that matches elements in any language (which, again, is pointless if you *don't care* what language an element is in!), but this assumes the document even has content language semantics built into it. It is not clear if `:lang()` will work at all in a document lacking such semantics.</sub>